# java.util.Random digging a bit deep

Tags: java, random, formula, probability

I was reading Data Structures and Algorithms in Java book and I came across the following question that I would like to get help with:

> Suppose you are given an array, A, containing 100 integers that were generated using the method r.nextInt(10), where r is an object of type java.util.Random. Let x denote the product of the integers in A. There is a single number that x will equal with probability at least 0.99. What is that number and what is a formula describing the probability that x is equal to that number?

I think `x` is equal to zero; as most probably 0 will be generated. However, that's just a guess. I wasn't able to find the formula. The [java documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) doesn't specify the randomization equation and I wasn't able to find any related topics either here or after searching using Google.

I would like to get some help with the probability formula please. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question is not about `java.util.Random`. It is general math question about probability -- any uniform random generator will lead to the same answer.

Comment: Since it is products, not sums as I mistakenly read, yes, `x` should be 0 most of the time. But there is a tiny chance that in those 100 numbers, not a single 0 will occur, hence the probability of 0.99. I'm not sure of the exact formula for that probability, but I believe it is along the lines of the 1 - (the probability of 0, which is 1/10, divided by the number of chances for it to happen, which is 100).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The possible values for the array elements are 0 .. 9, each with probability 1/10. If one of the elements is 0, the product will be 0 as well. So we calculate the probability that at least one element is 0.

It turns out, this is the opposite of all elements being greater than zero. The probability for an element to be greater than 0 is 9/10, and the probability that all elements are greater than zero is therefore (9/10)^100.

The probability that at least one element is 0 is therefore 1 - (9/10)^100 which is approximately 0.9999734.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding `nextInt`: The javadoc specifies:

> uniformly distributed int value between 0 (inclusive) and the
>   specified value (exclusive)

a "uniform distribution" is a distribution where each outcome is equally likely.

hence the chances for a particular outcome are "1/[number of possible outcomes]" (so they all add up to 1).

Regarding the array:
Filling the array can be regarded as observing 100 statistically independent events.

You should read up, on how the maths work when combining multiple independent events.

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt(int)

As you already expect, it will of be 0

```
r.nextInt(10)
```

will return numbers from 0 to 9

The product of any 0 * 1-9 will be 0, therefore for 100 random numbers, the chance that no 0 will be returned from this function is pretty low.